# Numpy: efficient way of filtering a very large array with a list of values

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I am manipulating a very large array of `int`s in numpy ( ). I want to filter it with a sublist of its values `sublist`. As the array is really large it looks like I need to be smart to do it in teh quickest way.

For instance:

```
my_array = N.random.randint(size=1e10)
sublist = [4,7,9]
#core where I extract the values of my_array equal to 4, 7 or 9
```

I've thought about:

```
cut = N.zeros((len(my_array)),dtype=bool)
for val in sublist:
    cut = cut | (my_array == val)
my_array = my_array[cut]
```

but it would have to parse the array `len(sublist)` amount of time.

Still manually:

```
cut = N.array([value in sublist for value in my_array])
my_array = my_array[cut]
```

but is there a more numpytonic way of doing so?

Comment: Is `my_array` sorted?

Comment: @Divakar: not in the most general case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`numpy.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) does exactly this. Your code would look like:

```
cut = N.in1d(my_array, sublist)
my_array = my_array[cut]
```